# Remove and replace patterns in strting

Tags: r

I want to remove the pattern `"-n\"` from a string and replace the pattern `"\n"` by a space.

For example:

```
"intelec-\ntual"
```

Shoudld be:

```
"intelectual"
```

And:

```
"diferentes\ntipos"
```

Should be:

```
"diferentes tipos"
```

I'm trying with different combinations of gsub, but no luck yet. 
For example:

```
gsub("[-\n]", "", output2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
> gsub("-\n","",s1,fixed = TRUE)
[1] "intelectual"

> gsub("\n"," ",s2,fixed = TRUE)
[1] "diferentes tipos"
```

**Data**

```
s1 <- "intelec-\ntual"
s2 <- "diferentes\ntipos"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a multi gsub solution you dont need to care about the order in which you carry out the substitution:

```
h <- c("intelec-\ntual", "diferentes\ntipos")

mgsub::mgsub(h, c("-\n", "\n"), c("", " "))
"intelectual"      "diferentes tipos"
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://regex101.com/

```
gsub("-?\n", "", c("intelec-\ntual", "diferentes\ntipos"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("diferentes\ntipos", pattern = "\\n", replacement = " ")
[1] "diferentes tipos"
str_remove_all("intelec-\ntual", pattern = "-\n")
[1] "intelectual"
```